# How to do a product of all rows in a column in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a column as below. I want to multiply all values together and get one value across

```
Yield
0.90
0.85
0.71
0.25

Yield Total_Prod
0.90   0.135
0.85   0.135
0.71   0.135
0.25   0.135
```

Where `Total_Prod = 0.90*0.85*0.71*0.25`

Comment: Please check https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-5620

Comment: Thanks. That works for RUNNING_PROD. But, how about Total() I want to display the Product() of the rows in a separate column

Comment: Whoever edited the question for formatting, thanks! I was struggling to get that right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Running product is given by this calculation as mentioned in comments](https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-5620)

[RP] : `EXP(RUNNING_SUM(LN(SUM([Yield]))))`

But to find the `Total Product` use this calculation :

```
LOOKUP([RP],LAST())
```

To get the output like this:

[image]

Reply to comment :

[Running total using Exp and Log rules](https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-5620) explains `exp and how formula works` and [More info on Lookup by examples](https://www.interworks.com/blog/tmccullough/2014/09/29/5-tableau-table-calculation-functions-you-need-know) 
the lookup is used to navigate the different results in your view.It takes parameters to give the navigational control.
[More Info on last](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/displaying-only-first-or-last-value-in-a-partition)
`Last value` in your view is the final result of the calculation.

Comment: Vijaykumar. This works! Could you please explain how Lookup and EXP plays a role here?

Comment: Also, wondering how I can reset the running_sum or running_total for every partition (dimension values) I have? Example, I have a column called Type with values R, O. How do I reset the running_sum/ total product for each partition value? I am using 9.1 and I have an option to edit default table calculation setting..however, it doesn't seem to work.        Type Yield  Total_Product
 R     0.90   0.135
 R     0.85   0.135
 R     0.71   0.135
 R     0.25   0.135

 O     0.70   0.09
 O     0.25   0.09
 O     0.61   0.09
 O     0.85   0.09

Comment: @Vids : I tried explained teh work around and you could post another question or add more details/data to your above question and expected output,for us to test.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Yield is always > 0

```
exp(sum(ln(Yield)))
```